# Magento connect : Connection Error try again later

Tags: magento

I am trying to install one extension using magento connect but the error I am getting :

> Connection Error try again later.

I am using extension key

```
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mageix_ExtensionManager
```

Comment: Are you using it locally?

Comment: No i am using on one development server

Comment: In your magento connect check the settings tab for use custom permissions and deployment type.

Comment: go to the var/cache folder and remove all the folder into it and then var/session and remove all the files also . Open your admin panel and then you will access the extension

Comment: I got the problem and i have installed manually and installed but the problem is when i am trying to logout magneto connect. It is redirecting to wrong url.

Answer (score 1):

I was just hit with this error - turns out the live server I had just moved the site too didn't have DOMDocument support in PHP. A quick `yum install php-xml` and restart of Apache fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the compatibility of the extension
2. Flush the cache in magento connect and check

Answer (score 0):

Installing `yum install php-xml` and restarting nginx worked for me.